# Merrill Lynch historical stock prices - where to find?

Tags: united-states, stocks, historical-data

I am currently working on a project concerning Merrill Lynch (MER) and I need its historical stock prices in order to calculate abnormal returns. However, I cannot find any of them, since it is long delisted and websites like Yahoo Finance, dailyfinance.com, Bloomberg, and similar do not hold it anymore in their databases. On FinData.com I stumbled upon only last 60 days (until 31 Dec 2008), yet it is too little for my calculations.

Can you help me out? Do you know where I can find such data that will show me adjusted close prices of MER in 2008?

Answer (score 1):

You could try asking Merrill Lynch, (general inquiries) :-

http://www.ml.com/index.asp?id=7695_114042

So far I only found a few graphics :-

[image]

[image]

[image]

1. http://topics.nytimes.com/top/news/business/companies/merrill_lynch_and_company/
2. http://www.reuters.com/article/2008/01/17/us-merrilllynch-results-idUSWNAS674520080117
3. http://www.stocktradingtogo.com/2008/09/15/merrill-lynch-saved-by-bank-of-america-buyout/